# Regex for three expressions with 'AND'

Tags: ruby, regex

I need to return `true` if a string matches three regexes. I have a lot of regex options around each regex pattern. I can use separate `match`/`scan` for each of the three values, and conjoin them with `AND` to see if they all return TRUE. The pipe does not work.

In the code below, I need to get `TRUE` only for the first `mystring3`:

```
mystr3= '  OK 3 values MyServer  and myNode  and myuser  TRUE '
mystr2= 'has on 2 values   mynode##  and .myserver should be FALSE'
mystr1= ' has on 1 values  Myserver  should be FALSE'

regex1 = /\bmyserver\b/i ;   regex2 = /\bmynode\b/i ;   regex3 = /\bmyuser\b/i

regex = /#{regex1}|#{regex2}|#{regex3}/  ## AND  /#{regex2}/  and /#{regex3}/

p  'match3 ' + mystr3.scan(regex).to_s
p  'match2 ' + mystr2.scan(regex).to_s
```

But I think there should be something easier than that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To check to see that the string matches *all* three, you can use lookahead for the subexpression three times:

```
regex = /^(?=.*#{regex1})(?=.*#{regex2})(?=.*#{regex3})/
```

Comment: Tx CP!!  I tried your regex on my sample strings, doesn't return anything, checking more,  will it work no matter of order of those keyboards, sorry forgot to mention this.

Comment: Works for me: https://repl.it/repls/InexperiencedWelcomeSpool Note that the matched substring, if any, will be the empty string, which is not the same thing as no match at all. Yes, no characters are consumed between the lookaheads, so they can be in any order.

Comment: Tx again, I need educate bit more myself, marked as answer.

Comment: All Ok for me now ,Tx again.

Comment: The point is that, if the string `str` matches all three regular expressions, `str =~ regex` or `str.match` or `str[regex]` all return a "truthy" value (a numeric offset, a `MatchData` object or an empty string, respectively); else all return `nil`. We can make any of these expressions return `true` or `false` by prefacing them with `!!`; for example, `!!(str =~ regex)`. Since this question was posted we have been given the method [String#match?](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.6.3/String.html#method-i-match-3F), which returns `true` or `false`.